# Fieldinfo.FieldType.FullName is not giving datatype for datetime and double

Tags: c#, reflection, visual-studio-2005

I am using Fieldinfo.FieldType.FullName to get the field datatype. 
For a string i get System.String
but for a Double i get

System.Nullable`1[[System.Double, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]

similarly for DateTime i get
System.Nullable`1[[System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]

i need to check in my code if this particular field is a datetime then do certain action.
How can i check that the field is a double or string or double etc

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JaredPar's answer is a nice explanation.  For a solution, try:

```
Type fieldType = fieldInfo.FieldType;
if (fieldType.IsGenericType && fieldType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
    fieldType = fieldType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
```

Now you can just say:

```
if (fieldType == typeof(double))
    ...
```

etc.  This code will basically "undo" the nullable type semantics.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the field in question is actually a `double?` and `DateTime?` and not a plain old `double` / `DateTime`.  The `?` trailing the type name is a shorthand for the full name `Nullable<double>` which is not the same as a `double`.

It sounds like you actually want to use this field though.  There are a couple of ways you could approach this

- Make the field type actually `double` instead of `double?`
- Do the action if the type is `double` or `double?`.

Comment: I am getting this data from salesforce. I am really not sure if the datatype is double or double?. My problem is how would i check which datatype is it. I am checking the datatype by using the FieldInfo class. Fieldinfo.FieldType.FullName. This returns the version culture etc along with the Syatem.DateTime. as mentioned in my question. How can i confirm the type is double or string or datetime in the If statement